# Stop, restore and restart MS SQL server

Tags: java, sql-server, database

I have a build deployed on my local and I am able to access the application using `https://localhost:8443/dashboard`. Now, as a part of my junits, I am supposed to take the backup of the database used by this application and restore it to its earlier state as the application inserts some data across multiple tables as a part of the tests. So, I need to restore the DB before the tests run. Now, I am able to backup and restore it using java program (junit) but the problem is coming when the server is running. It says `DB is already in use and can't restore`. Is there a way to disconnect the db connection (user) used in the application, do the restoration and then connect back again so that I don't have to shutdown the server and start it manually again.

Using commands similar to following -

```
  BACKUP DATABASE [Store] TO DISK = N'"+backuppath+"' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT, 
NAME = 'demodb-full', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10";
```

And

```
RESTORE DATABASE  ["+dbName+"] FROM DISK='"+database_backup_location+"' WITH
 REPLACE, MOVE '"+mdfLogicalName+"' TO 
'"+getPropertyByKey("databse.dbfiles.location")+mdfLogicalName+".mdf', MOVE 
'"+ldfLogicalName+"' TO 
'"+getPropertyByKey("databse.dbfiles.location")+ldfLogicalName+".ldf';
```

Error that I am getting -

```
    org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: StatementCallback;
 uncategorized SQLException for SQL [RESTORE DATABASE ....error code [3101]; 
Exclusive access could not be obtained because the database is in use.; nested 
exception is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Exclusive access 
could not be obtained because the database is in use.
```

Comment: There are SQL Server commands BACKUP and RESTORE, backup is done without any interruption of work, why don't you want to use them?

Comment: >>>Is there a way to disconnect the db connection (user) used in the application<<< alter database myDB set offline with rollback immediate

Comment: @sepupic, I am already using the BACKUP and RESTORE commands. RESTORE command gives error because the database is in use. That's what I need to overcome. Updated the commands in my question as well.

Answer (score 1):

> I am already using the BACKUP and RESTORE commands. RESTORE command
>   gives error because the database is in use.

I've already answered, you just need to set your database offline this way:

`alter database myDB set offline with rollback immediate`

Doing this you'll disconnect all the users from your db and now you can make a `RESTORE`

Comment: And how to restore the connections that were there already? It gets away with the error using it but I also loose the active connection on which my server was connected to it and application stops responding. Any way to restore the connections as well?

Comment: You have to do this on downtime

Comment: >>>And how to restore the connections that were there already<<< In no way. Any well-written application will retry the connect, but civilized people have a rule to email all the users in advance and notify them that on the date ... there will be database downtime due to restore, this way not only you warn your users about the downtime, but also they'll be aware of the data that will be at some moment in the past

Comment: @sepupic, I understand. The requirement is a bit weird. Anyways, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do below steps :

1. Backup the database

   BACKUP DATABASE [Store] TO DISK = N'"+backuppath+"' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT, 
   NAME = 'demodb-full', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10";
2. Kill existing connections

   USE master;

   DECLARE @kill varchar(8000); SET @kill = '';
   SELECT @kill = @kill + 'kill ' + CONVERT(varchar(5), spid) + ';'
   FROM master..sysprocesses
   WHERE dbid = db_id('Store')

   EXEC(@kill);
3. Then run the restore script.